# send location when app is in background when force closing it

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, background

Im developing an IOS application , which sends users location every 30 seconds to a backend server, even in its background. if i set it in the background(pressing the round button once on iphone), it sends successfully the location, but when i force close it(pressing the round iphone button twice , and force closing the app), location stops been sent.i get an error from the location request that i must login first. while when i press on the app icon , the app opens normally without any login.
my code below:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0f target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

and the request :

```
- (void)sendLocations{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self getLocation];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *statId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"statusId"];
    if(!(statId == nil)){
        [Requests updateUserLocation:(longitude) statusId:(statId) latitude:(latitude) block:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            if(success){
                NSLog(@"Location Sucessfully sent");
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"location Not Success");
            }
        }];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"NO Location");
    }
}
```

Comment: That timer-based approach won't work when your app isn't running under Xcode and if the user kills your app then it is dead because that is what they wanted.

Comment: so your telling me that there is no solution for this case?